# What should be the tag for problems arisen from communication with fellow Buddhists?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm looking for a tag that better describes these questions:

- [Why does Buddhism seem to have an anti-thought bias?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/22195/13525)
- [I explain why I prefer discuss Buddhism intellectually but others don't seem to accept my point. Why is that?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/31152/13525)
- [How to ask other Buddhists doing analysis, rather than advising me to stop analyzing?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/31193/13525)

Maybe doctrine-clinging? I hope someone who understand Buddhism and more fluent in English can help me.

Comment: Would you like a tag which describes problems -- any and all communication problems? Would topics like "How can I explain Buddhism to my mother?" and "How can I persuade my parents to let me ordain?" be included in that tag? Or are you looking for a tag which describes the activity of discussing/analysing doctrine -- which, is not necessarily/always a problem?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm looking for a tag describing the problems arising during discussing doctrines

Comment: I suspect a tag like "doctrine-clinging" may instigate rather than creating a more apt description of the topic. Would "doctrine" and "discussion" in combination cover a proper description?

Comment: @Erik you mean "doctrine-discussion"?

Comment: I mean adding "doctrine" as a separate tagword, because then it could be useful to have for other types of questions as well. It could then be combined along with the "discussion" tag, like in your question, or in combination with any other tagword when suitable. Having a pre-combined "doctrine-discussion" may be too narrow, compared to have it stand alone.

Comment: @Erik that would be a good point. I was too focused on running them together because I am having this enough, but for other people, they may feel it's not a big problem. You may want to make it as an answer

Comment: @Ooker thanks, i'll add it to the answers then.

Answer (score 1):

How about `intellectualism` or `rationalism`?

Answer (score 0):

In this new question, [When will a Buddhist accept doing analysis?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/35841/13525), I use these tags: [discussion](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) and [anti-thought](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-thought). I think anti-thought is a big topic in Buddhism and deserve a tag for it.

Comment: I don't like `anti-thought` because its your description of someone else's view. Instead I'd prefer your description of your view (e.g. `pro-thought` or whatever it is).

Comment: If you add a tag please [add a description](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1058) too of what it's used for, i.e. when/whether to use it for a given topic.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is adding "doctrine" as a separate tagword, because it could be useful for other types of questions as well. It could then be combined along with the "discussion" tag, like in your question, or in combination with any other tagword when suitable. Having a pre-combined "doctrine-discussion" may be too narrow, compared to have it stand alone.

Comment: I don't think 'doctrine' is good -- because more than half the questions on the site are about doctrine, in one way or another.

Comment: @ChrisW I didn't think prevalence of topics was an exclusion criteria for tags. Do you feel the same about tags like "theravada", "meditation" or "reference-request" for instance?

Comment: `theravada` has a purpose -- ""don't give non-theravada answers to this question, please". similarly `reference-request`-- "I just want the reference, thank you, and an answer without a reference is off-topic." But for example `buddhism` would be a very bad tag. And given that this site is only for "Buddhist doctrine and practice" I don't see the benefit of a "doctrine" tag which could be applicable to 70% of all the questions.

Comment: @ChrisW OK, i understand you better now.